# Getting a NaN on chrome while fetching the date

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a simple code for date validation. If **Start > End** date, pop up an alert. The dates are coming in from a query in the model class. I am displaying and editing them in the view class. First I had a problem in accessing the ID's, but after solving that issue, I keep getting the NaN on the date.

View Class:

```
 @if (item.Start!= null)
   {
     @Html.Hidden("Row_Status", 0)
        <td class="strt"> @Html.EditorFor(x => item.Start, "Start_Date", new { HtmlAttributes = new { @id = "Start_Date" } })</td>
   }

<td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.End, "End_Date", new { HtmlAttributes = new { @id = "End_Date" } })</td>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("td.strt").bind("change", function () {
                console.log("here");
                var cur_td = $(this).parent("tr.home");
                console.log("here now");
                var QA_date = cur_td.find("td.End_Date").val();
                console.log(QA_date);
                var test = new Date(QA_date).getTime();
            console.log(test);
     });
});
```

Output:

[image: The output on google chrome]

Anyway to solve this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: `(QA_date)..getTime();` <-- a typo?

Comment: a `<td>` element does not have a value

Comment: @epascarello that is not the problem haha, just a typo..

Comment: You have many syntax errors in your JS code. Please fix it first.

Comment: What is the HTML look like when it is rendered? Looking at serverside template code is bad.

Comment: @epascarello  its a date of this format "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: Again: What is the HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward really.

In your console logs, the third output is [Object object] (which is Not a Number).

In your code you use that very same object as the parameter to the Date() constructor. Since the Date() constructor doesn't know how to deal with that it fails, so then `getTime()` fails as well. When that happens, the Date() constructor returns `NaN` by design.

The root cause is this code:

```
var QA_date = cur_td.find("td.End_Date").val();
```

Since `td` DOM nodes do not have a value property/attribute, this doesn't work.

If the date string is inside the `td` then do this:

```
var QA_date = cur_td.find("td.End_Date").text();
```

Comment: That works for the QA_date, however gives me a blank on the dev_date.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

QA_date is not receiving the correct value of your input. Check your selectors according to your HTML code. "td.End_Date" selects a tag **td** with the class **End_Date**, I am pretty sure that is not what you want. Watch the following example to check the difference in CSS selectors. One have a **blank space** between **div** and **.sample**, and the other one not

```js
// inputContent equals to "2018-01-01"
var inputContent = $('div .sample').val();
console.log("This is the content of the input :" + inputContent ) ;

// divContent equals to empty string ""
var divContent = $('div.sample').val();
console.log("This is the content of the div :" + divContent) ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sample">
      <input type="text" value="2017-01-01" /> 
</div>
<div> 
    <input type="text" class="sample" value="2018-01-01" /> 
</div>
```

Also, check your selectors, the dot (**.**) selector is for selecting an element by using the class attribute, according to your Razor code, I think you might be better off by using the **#** selector, which selects the element according to the ID attribute, like this *'td #End_Date'*

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data this is harder to debug but I think your error may be because your Date object is not able to parse your string parameter properly.

I would build the date in a more structured manner as follows:

```
// assumes parameter date is in format dd-mm-yyy, adjust accordingly

function getDateFromString(dateString) {

    var returnDate = new Date();
    var splitDateString = dateString.split('-');

    returnDate.setDate(splitDateString[0]);
    returnDate.setMonth(parseInt(splitDateString[1]) - 1); // jscript date months begin at 0
    returnDate.setFullYear(splitDateString[2]);

    return returnDate;
}
```

Edit:

As pointed out by Randy Casburn, the definitive error here is trying to get a value (val()) from a td element. You need to use text() instead. I would still recommend building your date objects manually though